# Configure traffic 2 NICs for different IP Ranges

Tags: windows-7, windows, routing

I have two NICs in my PC. One is connected to home network which connects to the internet through ADSL. Second is connected directly to a 4G router of another ISP. My need is, I want to configure my Windows 7 PC such that when I send a request to an IP from home network (ex. 192.172.1.5 which is my home web server) should go though 1st NIC and all the other requests (ex. when I access google.com) should go though 2nd NIC (i.e 4G)

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be too hard to do.  Simply don't set a default gateway on the NIC that uses the 192.175.1.xxx addresses.

A default gateway uses the most generic/wide/biggest subnet size/length/mask/prefix, which is 0.0.0.0

Assuming that your first NIC has a more specific subnet mask (like 255.255.255.0), then all 192.175.1.xxx addresses that fit within that subnet will go out the first NIC.  If your system's only default gateway is an address that is in the 2nd NIC's subnet, then traffic to other sites (worldwide) will go to the default gateway, which will use the 2nd NIC (because the default gateway's address is in the 2nd NIC's subnet).